# When 301 redirecting a page, what needs to be in the sitemap?

Tags: 301-redirect, sitemap, pagerank

In sitemap there was page `a.html` which has some PageRank. 
Now `a.html` is redirecting to `b.html` using `301` and sitemap has `b.html` entry, `a.html` is removed.

Queries are:

1. As `a.html` is not in sitemap then how search engines understand `301` redirection of `a.html` to `b.html` and add PageRank of `a.html` to`b.html`?
2. Will search engines still crawl `a.html`?  How much longer?
3. Is it necessary for the sitemap to have both entries: `a.html` and `b.html` for some time so search engines resolve query 1 as mentioned above?

Comment: There's been comments from Bing devs that if you have dirt (301's, 404's etc) in your sitemaps they will not crawl them.  I would not be surprised if Google has similar policies. Here's a good discussion on this. http://moz.com/blog/uncrawled-301s-a-quick-fix-for-when-relaunches-go-too-well

Comment: Thanks @jeffatrackaid, Its really helpful and in detail discussion. Actually I am worried about exactly same scenario mentioned there. What I concluded is, after redirecting pages to new ones for some time keep old entries in sitemap so crawler visit those pages and knows `301` redirection. If I am missing anything please correct.

Comment: You should not have 301s in your sitemaps.  The updates are not instant.  If you look at your logs, you will see the bots continuing to hit the old URls for quite some time.  It is not as if they process a sitemap and forget their prior search map for your site.

Comment: PS: After a week observations. Organic traffic dropped to almost zero for all pages which are `301` redirected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answers:

1. Search engines bots are web crawlers (like your web browser in some way) and when a 301 redirect is thrown, they are notified. Therefore, they follow the new redirect to reach the new page and know the PageRank must be transferred.
2. If the 301 redirect is up, search engines don't crawl `a.html` anymore, that's why after a long time, they remove this page from their index.
3. You did the right thing regarding the *sitemap.xml*, you must remove pages which are 301 redirected (indeed, the *sitemap.xml* file is useful for indexing and these pages mustn't be indexed anymore).